# Apache Sling, Lock on LOCAL_REVISONS table

Tags: oracle, apache, websphere, sling, jackrabbit

We use Apache Sling 7 (jackrabbit-core 2.6.5) with 2 clusters on a WAS WebSphere Platform 8.5 (Java version (IBM) 1.6.0).

The configuration of the Jackrabbit repository (uses ORACLE database) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Repository
      PUBLIC "-//The Apache Software Foundation//DTD Jackrabbit 2.0//EN"
      "http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/repository-2.0.dtd">
<Repository>

<FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.OracleFileSystem">
    <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
    <param name="url" value="{DATA_SOURCE}"/>
    <param name="schema" value="oracle"/>
    <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="SLING_"/>
</FileSystem>

<DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore">
    <param name="path" value="{DATA_STORE_PATH}/datastore"/>
    <param name="minRecordLength" value="100"/>
</DataStore>

<Security appName="Jackrabbit">
    <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager" workspaceName="security">
    </SecurityManager>
    <AccessManager class="org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.server.impl.security.PluggableDefaultAccessManager">
    </AccessManager>
    <LoginModule class="org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.server.impl.security.PluggableDefaultLoginModule">
        <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous"/>
        <param name="adminId" value="admin"/>
    </LoginModule>
</Security>    

<Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default"/>
<Workspace name="${wsp.name}">
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
        <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}"/>
    </FileSystem>
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager">
        <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
        <param name="url" value="{DATA_SOURCE}"/>
        <param name="tablespace" value=""/>
        <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false"/>
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="SLING_${wsp.name}_"/>  
    </PersistenceManager>
    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
        <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
        <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
    </SearchIndex>
</Workspace>

<Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/version" />
    </FileSystem>
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager">
        <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
        <param name="url" value="{DATA_SOURCE}"/>
        <param name="tablespace" value=""/>
        <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false"/>
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="SLING_VERSION_"/>
    </PersistenceManager>
</Versioning>

<SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
    <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/index"/>
    <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
</SearchIndex>

<Cluster id="{CLUSTER_ID}" syncDelay="2000">
    <Journal class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.journal.OracleDatabaseJournal">
        <param name="revision" value="${rep.home}/revision.log" />
        <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
        <param name="url" value="{DATA_SOURCE}"/>
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="SLING_"/>
    </Journal>
</Cluster>    

</Repository>
```

From time to time, even if there is no activity on the application, the SLING_LOCAL_REVISONS table remains locked, we must unlock the table and restart the WAS cluster.
The lock is on a request : update SLING_LOCAL_REVISIONS set REVISION_ID = ? where JOURNAL_ID = ?

To know where these updates of SLING_LOCAL_REVISIONS table came from, I modified the DatabaseJournal class to use my own ConnectionHelper class in which I add stack traces logs.
The updates come from:

- The modification of data by a client of the application.
- Cluster updates using the Journal.
- And many updates that come from the "discovery" component.

I think that the blocking occurs between these 2 last points with REVISION_ID which are sometimes identical.
This is bizarre especially because the method that performs the updates is synchronized (DatabaseJournal.DatabaseRevision.set).

Do you know this kind of problem and how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: This may be a question for the jackrabbit user's list. But overall I would encourage you to switch to Sling 8 and Oak and it's better maintained and supported.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
We can not use Sling 8 because we can not change Java version.
In the meantime, we use the journal in file mode.